# How can I find the fixed points of this Duffing oscillator differential equation?

Tags: mathematical-physics, nonlinear-dynamics

The problem is to find the fixed points for the equation:
$$\ddot{x}+ \dot{x}- x + ax^3=b \cos(ct)$$
where $a,b$ and $c$ are constants.

The Duffing oscillator is a 2nd order differential equation and I know that we can find the fixed points with the following substitution:
$$\dot{x}=y$$

Then we get a system:
$$\dot{x}=y$$
$$\dot{y}=\ddot{x}$$

From the first equation we get:
$$\dot{x}=y=0$$

But how do I approach the second equation?
$$\dot{y}=\ddot{x}=-\dot{x}+ x - ax^3+b \cos(ct)=0$$

Comment: Let $x=x_1, \dot{x}=x_2$. A fixed point occurs when $\dot{x}_1=\dot{x}_2=0$, i.e
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}_{1}\\
\dot{x}_{2}
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
x_{2}\\
{-x_{2} +x_{1} -ax_{1}}^{3} +b\cos( ct)
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$
From the first equation, we have $x_2=0$ hence from the second equation we get a cubic polynomial:
$$x_1-a{x_1}^3+b\cos(ct)=0$$
You can either use the cubic formula or just find the solutions numerically. In any case the fixed points will depend on the time $t$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot!